# How to separate code from one route file to many and how to call function from this separated files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written code in `app.js` as :

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var routes=require("./routes/routes1")(app);//ipn listner

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

Rest of my code is in `./routes/routes1.js` under root folder;
I have many functions under it but few function are related to same entity

Example:

- `fun1`, `fun2`, `fun3` are related to `customer` entity
- `fun4`, `fun5` are related to other entity
- but `fun1` may call `fun5`

Problem is I need to seperate `fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3` into separate .js file.
How can i do so and how can I call function of other file into one file?

Comment: You only showed us the basis of a express app, and your question is about the routing. You could put your `funX` in different files and `require` them, but that is yet another question. This question is too broad as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad but here is example that may help you. You may like to create following directory structure

```
myapp
├── app.js
├── _function
│   ├── func1.js
│   ├── func2.js
│   ├── func3.js
│
├── _routes
│   ├── routes1.js
│   ├── routes2.js
```

where `myapp` is root foot folder(project folder) while `routes` folder contains all routes and `function` folder contains all function that can be use in other js files

**`app.js`**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var routes1 = require("./routes/routes1");
var routes2 = require("./routes/routes2");

// http://localhost:3000/routes1
app.use('/routes1', routes1);

// http://localhost:3000/routes2 // http://localhost:3000/routes2/list
app.use('/routes2', routes2);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

**`func1.js`**

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
    var add = arg1 + arg2;
    return add;
}
```

**`func2.js`**

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
    var add = arg1 * arg2;
    return add;
}
```

**`func3.js`**

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
    var add = arg1 - arg2;
    return add;
}
```

**`routes1.js`**

```
var express = require('express');

var func1 = require('../function/func1');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var result = func1(2, 3);
    res.json({func1: result, url: req.url, message:'success'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**`routes2.js`**

```
var express = require('express');

var func2 = require('../function/func2');
var func3 = require('../function/func3');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var result = func2(2, 3);
    res.json({func1: result, url: req.url, message:'success'});
});

router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
    var result = func3(2, 3);
    res.json({func1: result, url: req.url, message:'success'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

I hope this will help you to understand how to use a function into another  files